# Assembling an ASM file into an EXE

Tags: assembly, nasm

I just started learning the assembly language programming few days ago. Now I have a problem assembling the `asm` file into an `exe`. I use NASM as my assembler. This is the command I use to assemble it:

```
nasm file.asm -o file.com or exe
```

Here is my code:

```
.model small
.data
.code
start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov ax,00h
mov bx,33h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end start
```

...but I get these errors:

```
boss.asm:1: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
boss.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected
boss.asm:2: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
boss.asm:3: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
boss.asm:13: error: parser: instruction expected
```

I don't understand what these errors mean. How do I fix these errors?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help you without any code? We can't read your mind (or your monitor) from here, and that's what it would take to help you based on the information provided.

Comment: This looks like MASM source that you're trying to compile with NASM. You should look for a tutorial that uses NASM instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time but I think this can be caused by a lack of proper segment definitions.